# Ignore and propagate QWidget click events to the OS

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, qevent, qmouseevent

I have a top-level parentless `QWidget` on top of which I have a bunch of other `QWidgets`(e.g. `QPushButton`s). I would like to make my `QWidget` act like it is transparent for mouse events. So when I click on the `QWidget`(but not on my buttons) I want my window to lose focus and something in the back to be selected(e.g. a Windows Explorer window if it happens to be in the back of my window). I also want my `QPushButton`s to continue processing mouse events.

Is this possible? I tried setting the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` and `Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` on the widget but if I draw something on it, e.g. a `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` the widget still processes mouse click events on the parts where `QGraphicsDropShadowEffect` draws on it.

Is this possible?

Regards!

Comment: What version of Qt is this, and what platform? Last time I checked, `WA_TransparentForMouseEvents` only acted within the widget hierarchy and would not pass any mouse events "back" to the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some solution. In my case this - is the pointer to `QMainWindow`. Main idea: catch click, get `globalPos`, hide window and give click to OS. But it should be OS specific code, I can give you example which works on Windows. You should create `eventFilter` (I hope you know how to do this, so I post next code).

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if(obj == this && event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        qDebug() << "mouse";
        QMouseEvent *mouse = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        qDebug() << mouse->globalPos();
        QPoint point = mouse->globalPos();
        this->hide();
        //start of OS specific code
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,point.x(),point.y(),0,0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,point.x(),point.y(),0,0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,point.x(),point.y(),0,0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,point.x(),point.y(),0,0);
        //this->show();//as you want
    }

return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

In my example, window will hide and we emulate doubleclick. On my computer I can ignore `QMainWindow` and open picture which was closed by `QMainWindow`(I couldn't saw it, I saw only my `QMainWindow`, but click was ignored and we gave this click to OS)